# jQuery check dom for element using .length

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery to toggle a div if another div does not show in the dom. 
I've got a jsfiddle going, but so far no luck

```
if ( $("div.nothere").length > 0 ) {
    $("div.showme".toggle();
```

}

I'm overtired and think I might be getting hung up on a small syntax error.
Anyone see the problem? http://jsfiddle.net/NFQCc/

Comment: You're missing a right paren `)` after `"div.showme"`... Check the error console next time - Firebug clearly states `"missing ) after argument list" line 22`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (!$('div.nothere').length){
    $('div.showme').toggle();
}
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: mine has indentation and 2 extra spaces. mine is better ;)

Comment: That's strange that it works when you don't specify the length. 
Whats the logic there?

Comment: Its because JS loosely interprets zero as being false.

Answer (score 4):

```
if ( !$("div.nothere").length ) {
        $("div.showme").toggle();
}
```